# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted. Laravel + MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel

I have around 60 APIs in Laravel application and every time an API is called the below error is generated in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

> [:error] [pid 19695] [client 49.205.220.112:14141] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 88 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 522, referer: http://example.com/home?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1Ni....
>
> [core:notice] [pid 6016] AH00051: child pid 19695 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

**free -m**

[image]

Just for experimenting purpose I tried to use below the code statements in a few APIs, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '1200');
ini_set('max_input_time', 0);   // 0 to allow unlimited time
```

The technologies I've used are `PHP >=5.5.9, Laravel 5.2.*, mongodb ^3.0`

I saw few other posts with same the issue, but none of the answers worked for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Disabling memory limit is the worst you can do and won't fix a thing. Instead you should fix your code, which is causing memory usage to spike. Unless your code does something time consuming (video conversion, image manipulations etc.) then you are clearly doing it wrong.

Comment: well this error is generated for all the api's invoked even for a simple save, query, delete etc is generates this error..

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this error is generated because lack of server memory.
Check if your server has enough memory to run your application. Run your api and watch server memory usage.

And in some environment, ini_set doesn't work in php safe mode. check your php.ini and set safe_mode off.

And I'm curious where did you put ini_set

Comment: `ini_set` was put in function which is triggered by routes.. not in all functions but only few for testing purposes

Comment: included the snapshot of memory from server

Comment: `sql.safe_mode = Off` is present in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file

Comment: Php.ini in cli directory is not a right one. Check php_info()

Comment: php -c /etc/php/apache2/php.ini -i   -> php_info() -> `sql.safe_mode => Off => Off`